# Sessions not being resumed after Meteor server restart

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, meteor, rxjs

I am using ionic/angular with a meteor backend. Everything has been going smooth, but I am currently testing the authentication and have noticed that the user is logged out every time the server is restarted. I didn't notice this issue with standalone Meteor.

The `Meteor.loginToken` and `Meteor.loginTokenExpires` values are set in the browsers local storage and there are tokens in the `services.resume.loginTokens` property in the `users` collection in MongoDB.

`Meteor 1.10.2`
`Angular 7.3.9`

This is my login function:

```
    async login(email, password) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    this.toastService.present(error.reason, "danger");
                    return reject(error);
                }

                this.toastService.present("Login successful");
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
```

The login works fine, but upon restarting the server, Meteor.user() returns null. Any suggestions?

Comment: Whoever voted to close - it should not be closed. Usually even a server restart should not automatically log out the user unless you have routines on the server-startup that cause users to be logged out. Before going further here, please show the code-part, where you log `Meteor.user()` and it is null.